# What happens to outstanding stores after an object is deleted?

Tags: c++, multithreading, x86, cpu-architecture, memory-barriers

Consider the following simple function (assume most compiler optimizations turned off) being executed by two threads on different cores on an X86 CPU with a store buffer:

```
struct ABC
{
  int x;
  //other members.
};
void dummy(int index)
{
  while(true)
  {
    auto abc = new ABC;
    abc->x = index;
    cout << abc->x;
    // do some other things.
    delete abc;
  }
}
```

Here, index is the index of the thread; 1 passed by thread1 and 2 passed by thread2.
So, thread1 should always print 1 and thread2 should always print 2.

Can there be a situation where the store to x is put in the store buffer and is committed after delete is executed? Or is there an implicit memory barrier that ensures the store is committed before delete? Or is it that any outstanding stores are just discarded once delete is encountered?

Situation where this becomes important:

Since delete returns the memory of the object to the free list (with libc), it is possible that a piece of memory that was just free'd in thread1 is returned by the new operator in thread2 (not only the virtual address, even the underlying physical address returned can be the same).
If outstanding stores can execute after delete, it is possible that after thread2 sets abc->x to 2, some older outstanding store from thread1 overwrites it to 1.

This means that in the above program, thread2 can print 1 which is absolutely wrong. Thread1 and thread2 are completely independent and there is no data sharing between the threads from programmer's point of view and they should not have to worry about any synchronization.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you check, what standard says about sequensing of those operations?

Comment: Explain how you see a compiler reordering these 2 lines: `abc->x = index; cout << abc->x;`

Comment: I'm no expert on the lower levels of hardware behavior, but I don't see how this kind of situation can be possible. Storing data into `abc->x` will fully execute before `delete abc` is executed, so there can never be any "outstanding stores" like you describe.

Comment: @ixSci There will not be a compiler reordering here. My concern here is the behavior of the processor and how it buffers stores for performance.  Assume no compiler optimization for this example to simplify things.

Comment: @user1165136 I think it is pretty hard to answer this question from a HW POV w/o seeing what exactly IO and memory manager are doing in this code. `cout <<` & `delete` look simple but are doing much.

Comment: The x86 processor cannot reorder stores in the way you imagine. I'm sure you can google a description of x86 memory ordering that is much clearer and more detailed than I can put in this comment. But the short answer is you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I have been reading a lot about memory ordering but I haven't come across this particular behavior where even though there is no data sharing between the two threads from a programmer's POV, the actual memory used by thread2 could be accessed by thread1 to commit an outstanding store from its store buffer. Now i am pretty sure this is not how it happens. But haven't found out why it doesn't happen?

Comment: The fact that there is a delete and a new in between the two accesses is invisible to the processor and doesn't affect the processor's behavior.  The key point is that the delete is ordered after thread 1 writes 1 to the buffer; the new is ordered after that; and thread 2 writes 2 after that. So the value 1 cannot overwrite the value 2.

Comment: Also _I think_ that the memory manager should at least guarantee acq/rel relationship between new/delete. So all the writes will be visible before the new `new`.

Comment: Under to _as-if rule_, the C++ standard prescribes some observable behavior for your code. Implementations then must provide this behavior on particular computer systems. That's all you need to care about. In your situation, I don't think that the standard allows that write to happen after the target memory has been deallocated. If it's not possible by the standard, then the implementation must guarantee it won't happen at runtime.

Comment: @prl I haven't found anything online that talks about how delete or free ensure outstanding stores are either committed or discarded.  Also, this is not about reordering. This is about the processor putting the store in the store buffer as an optimization. I am not sure why you think that will not happen here. Is there any reason why in this particular case,  the store will get committed before delete and not put in the store buffer? If you are aware of such a reason, that is the answer to my question.

Comment: The CPU has to preserve the *illusion* of instructions executing one at a time, in program order.  This is the cardinal rule of OoO exec.  (It doesn't work like reordering statements in the C++ source.) If the `free` involves a `munmap` that uses a `syscall` instruction to kernel code that changes page tables, that will provide sufficient serialization.  If page table modification isn't involved, then the store buffer (and load buffer) will make sure loads see store-forwarding from earlier stores in this thread, but not from later stores.

Comment: @prl yes, that is assuming something in the standard somewhere guarantees that outstanding stores cannot cross the delete boundary. If they can (which i pretty sure is not the case), then outstanding store of x= 1 in thread1 can execute after x=2 in thread2. The processor running thread1 is not aware of thread2. Just trying to understand who/what guarantees this. And what exactly is the guarantee? Is it that outstanding stores are discarded or is it that they are committed before delete?

Comment: @PeterCordes Great insights as always! This is to do with the case where munmap is not called on free. Verified with strace. That observation is what lead to this concern since thread2 can immediately get the same memory chunk just used by thread1. I understand store-forwarding can help for a core to see/load the latest value from its store buffer. But this question is about what happens when the store is eventually committed by thread1? By the time it is committed, the memory might be held by thread2. Something should be keeping this from happening. Like something the standard maybe.

Comment: If new and delete are atomic, not two processes will get the same memory block simultaneously. They create an implicit mutual exclusion section.

Comment: Was working on turning that comment into an answer.  Just updated it to directly address that inter-thread concern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Within a single thread

**The CPU has to preserve the *illusion* of instructions executing one at a time, in program order, for a single thread.  This is the cardinal rule of OoO exec.**  This means tracking what program order was, and making sure loads always see values consistent with that, and that values eventually written to cache are also consistent.

This is very much like C++'s "as-if" rule, just with different observables that need to be preserved.  (C++ is very restrictive in what other threads are legally allowed to observe, unlike CPU ISAs, but neither compile-time nor run-time memory-reordering can be explained by reordering source lines<sup>1</sup>)

Loads by this core snoop the store buffer, forwarding data from it if the load is reloading a store that hasn't committed yet.

And for any individual memory location, making sure its modification order matches program order, i.e. not reordering stores to the same location.  So the final value after the dust settles is the last one in program order.  And even observation by other threads will see a consistent modification order for that location; that's why `std::atomic` is able to provide the guarantee that a modification order exists for every object separately, not having extra changes to A then B then back to A if program order stored B then A.  ISO C++ can guarantee this because all real-world CPUs also guarantee it.

A system call like `munmap` is a special case, but otherwise **`new`/`delete` (and `malloc`/`free`) aren't special as far as the CPU is concerned**: putting a block on the free list and having other code allocate it is just another case of messing around with pointer-based data structures.  As always, the CPU tracks any reordering its doing to make sure loads see correct values.

---

### Reuse by another thread

You're not wrong to worry about this; correctness doesn't happen for free here based on CPU architecture alone; a buggy libc could get this wrong and allow exactly the problems you describe.  [@ixSci's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71733357/what-happens-to-outstanding-stores-after-an-object-is-deleted/71733925#71733925) quotes the relevant part of the C++ standard.  (Compile-time ordering of memory access wrt. calls to new/delete is also necessary, but that always has to happen for any non-inline function call that the compiler doesn't know is "pure"; any function might read or write memory so it has to be in sync.)

If the memory is placed on a global free-list that could be reused by another thread, **a thread-safe allocator** will have used sufficient synchronization to create a C++ **happens-before relationship** between the code that previously used then deleted the memory, and the code in another thread that just allocated it.

So any old-thread stores into this memory block will already be visible to the thread that just allocated the memory.  So they won't step on its stores.  If the new thread passes a pointer to this memory to a 3rd thread, it had better use acq/rel or consume/release synchronization itself to make sure that 3rd thread sees its stores, not still stores from the first thread.

---

### Unmapping entirely so access to that virtual address faults

**If the `free` involves a `munmap`** that uses a `syscall` instruction to run kernel code that changes page tables (**to invalidate a mapping so loads/stores to it would fault**), that itself will provide sufficient serialization.  Existing CPUs don't rename the privilege level, so they don't do out-of-order exec into the kernel through a syscall instruction.

It's up to the OS to do sufficient memory-barriering around modifying page tables, although on x86-64 `invlpg` is already a *serializing instruction*.  (In x86 terminology, that means draining the ROB and store buffer, so all previous instructions are fully done executing with their results written back to L1d cache (for stores).)  So there's no possibility of it reordering with earlier loads / stores that depend on that TLB entry, even apart from the switch to kernel mode.

(Switching into kernel mode doesn't necessarily drain the store buffer, though; the physical address of those stores are known.  The TLB checks were done as the store-address uops were executed.  So changes to the page tables don't affect the process of committing them to memory.)

---

#### Footnote 1: memory reordering isn't source reordering

BTW, memory reordering doesn't work like reordering statements in the C++ source or instructions in the asm machine code; memory reordering is about what *other* threads can observe as loads read from cache and stores eventually commit to cache at the far end of the store buffer.  Reordering the source to try to explain this break the code, violating the as-if rule, but memory-reordering *can* produce such effects while still having the thread's operations see correct values for its own stores, e.g. by store-forwarding.  That's because real-world ISAs don't have sequentially consistent memory models; you need extra ordering to recover SC.  Even an in-order CPU pipeline can reorder loads with a cache that can hit-under-miss, for example, and even strongly-ordered x86 allows StoreLoad reordering: its memory model is basically program-order plus a store buffer with store-forwarding.

(There was discussion in comments about compile-time reordering and source ordering; the question didn't have this misconception.)

The C++ as-if rule is the same idea that CPUs follow as they execute, just that the ISA's rules are what govern the requirements on external observables.  No ISA has memory-ordering rules as weak as ISO C++, e.g. they all guarantee a coherent shared cache, and many CPU ISAs don't have UB.  (Although some do, e.g. calling it "unpredictable" behaviour.  Much more often just an unpredictable or undefined *result* in some register; user/supervisor privilege separation requires there be limits on what behaviour is possible so user-space can't run some unsupported instruction sequence and maybe take over or crash the whole machine.)

Fun fact: on strongly-ordered x86 specifically, store and load ordering need to be more closely tied together than most ISAs; Intel calls the combination of store buffer + load buffer the Memory Order Buffer, because it also has to detect cases where a load took a value early, before it was architecturally allowed to (LoadLoad ordering), but then it turns out this core lost access to the cache line.  Or in case of mis-speculation about store-forwarding, e.g. dynamically predicting that a load would be reloading a store from an unknown address, but then it turns out the store was non-overlapping.  In either case, the CPU rewinds the out-of-order back-end back to a consistent retirement state.  (This is called a pipeline nuke; this specific cause is counted by the `machine_clears.memory_ordering` perf event.)

Comment: I understand the intent of your statement - it's much easier for compiler vendors if CPU's hide their specific OoO implementation, and it certainly helps with compatibility between CPU models. But their is historical evidence that it's not a hard requirement - MIPS and SPARC had branch delay slots. Those leak an OoO implementation detail.

Comment: @MSalters: Branch delay slots actually aren't a counter-example to what I said; For example MIPS R10000 (4-wide OoO exec) still had to preserve the illusion of running 1 instruction at a time, it's just that program order includes running the instruction after a branch before the branch target.  The ISA defines what program order is.  Actual exceptions to that rule are things like VLIW where a bundle of instructions must be free from hazards.  Or The Mill, where you can have loads that produce their result 5 instructions from now, and instructions before that can still use the old reg val.

Comment: @MSalters: A better example of hazards leaking out is MIPS I *load* delay slots, where it wasn't guaranteed what happened if you read a register in the instruction after a load, because it wouldn't stall for load-use latency.  Machine without Interlocked Pipeline Stages until MIPS II added checking to improve I$ code density for cases where compilers couldn't fill it with something useful, and had to use a NOP.  (I've read that the actual result you got was the old value unless a cache miss or interrupt happened on that insn boundary, then you got the load result.)

Comment: (Branch delay slots were also considered a mistake, but couldn't be changed without breaking binary compatibility: which instructions run in what order.  Load delay slots could be removed by adding a new guarantee, making it safe to do something that was previously unsafe, so it could be assumed that there wasn't any existing code doing it.  But all existing MIPS programs did depend on branch-delay semantics.)

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes. In short, it is up to libc to ensure correct memory barriering when it puts a free'd object in the global free list that can be consumed by other threads. If munmap is called of free, then we  expect OS to take care of the memory barriers. There is no situation where an outstanding store to a to-be-deleted object can be discarded as an optimization right? I don't think there is even an instruction to do that.

Comment: @user1165136: Right, exactly.  And no, I don't think discarding still-pending stores is a thing.  On a weakly-ordered ISA, you could theoretically imagine having a MESI invalidate request from another core snoop the store buffer and remove pending stores to it.  (e.g. after a full-line write by another core it might just invalidate instead of RFO, since it doesn't need the old data).  But x86 couldn't easily do that because of strong store-ordering guarantees; killing those store-buffer entries would be equivalent to committing them early, before others from this core, and other core's store.

Comment: @user1165136: If a store has already committed to L1d cache from the store buffer, then it's already globally visible.  At that point the cache line can just be invalidated by another core doing a full-line write, like x86 does for `movnt` or `rep stos`/`rep movs`, or potentially even for normal (not NT) AVX512 aligned ZMM stores that write a full 64-byte cache line.  Or for AMD's `clzero` instruction which has NT-store semantics.  All could use no-RFO store protocols (at least NT stores and rep-movs/stos actually do), but that's not cancelling a store before it's visible.

Comment: @user1165136: I don't expect that any existing designs for other ISAs do snoop the store buffer when an invalidate comes in; it seems like a rare corner case that wouldn't be worth the transistors / power it would probably cost to support being able to actually kill some queued stores.  That would probably create a bunch of corner cases for store-forwarding, too, for this cores loads reloading those locations.

Answer (score 6):

According to C++20 (new.delete.dataraces/p1) we have the following guarantee:

> Calls to these functions that allocate or deallocate a particular unit
> of storage shall occur in a single total order, and each such
> deallocation call shall happen before (6.9.2) the next allocation (if
> any) in this order.

Since every `delete` *happens before* any `new` of the same memory, then what is *sequenced before* these operators also *happens before* these other invocations. And to your example:

`abc->x = index;` is sequenced before `delete abc;` which happens before `auto abc = new ABC;` and transitively `abc->x = index;` happens before `auto abc = new ABC;`. That guarantees that the `abc->x = index;` is complete before `auto abc = new ABC;`.

Comment: Nitpick: not before *any* `new`, just before any `new` *that re-allocates this memory*.  But yes, this is the key part of ISO C++ that guarantees thread-safe allocators, when combined with how CPUs work.  I guess you're saying that in the context of reallocation for a specific block, but it wouldn't hurt to make that explicit.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks! I've corrected the answer

Comment: Tweaked your wording a bit (and removed italics on the new part) to help it read as easily as it did before.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not sure that the "same memory" is a correct term here. What if the deallocated chunk was of some 8 points size and then it was merged into 16 points chunk and allocated. As I understand it it still should be serialized and it might still be called as "a particular unit of storage" but the memory won't be the same.

Comment: It's an intentional simplification.  Readers that think of corner cases like that can check the ISO C++ wording you quoted, but I hoped it would be obvious that "same memory" could mean "a block including any of the same bytes".

Comment: @ixSci Thank you for the answer. I think this combined with Peter's answer addresses this question!

Comment: @user1165136: That's correct; this answer is important.  I just updated mine again to link this for the quote from the standard, and to add section headers and reinforce the point that HW alone doesn't guarantee correctness for inter-thread memory allocators.  A buggy / unsafe libc could produce the effect you're talking about on real weakly-ordered ISAs like AArch64.